# How to show server date on when calender popup

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-applications, ajaxcontroltoolkit

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBirthDate" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" onkeydown="return txtBirthDate_OnKeyDown();"
                    class="csstextbox" runat="server" Width="175px"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:CalendarExtender ID="calendarBirthDate" OnClientDateSelectionChanged="calendarBirthDate_DateSelectionChanged"
                    runat="server" Enabled="True" 
                    TargetControlID="txtBirthDate" Format="dd-MMM-yyyy">
                </asp:CalendarExtender>
```

[image]

Showing in calender popup client date I have to show server date (this is client date "Today:November 13,2012")

Comment: Can't you just send the server date and time to the client and display that?

Comment: In no event. Either in the code, or you program a web service. NOt everythng is an event in programming.